# gin_trgm_ops index creation fails

Tags: postgresql, index

I'm trying to create a trigram index on a text filed containing names. I've added the pg_trgm extenion to the schema. Running `\dx` shows it is enabled:

```
List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |   Schema   |                            Description                            
-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 btree_gin | 1.3     | pg_catalog | support for indexing common datatypes in GIN
 dblink    | 1.2     | wos_core   | connect to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database
 pg_trgm   | 1.4     | wos_core   | text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(4 rows)
```

However when I run the following:

```
CREATE INDEX authors_full_name_idx ON wos_core.interface_table USING GIN (authors_full_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR:  operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
                                                 version                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit
```

Comment: Bingo! If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema `wos_core` is probably not in your search_path.

In that case, you need to prefix the operator with the schema name:

```
CREATE INDEX authors_full_name_idx 
       ON wos_core.interface_table USING GIN (authors_full_name wos_core.gin_trgm_ops);
```

Alternatively you can change the search path of your user, to include `wos_core`:

```
alter user your_username set search_path = 'public,wos_core,...';
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/335, in my case I had to drop the extension:

```
drop extension if exists pg_trgm;
```

And then I created it again with this:

```
create extension pg_trgm with schema [schemaName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok for me the version of postgres I was using was different - once I upgraded to higher version - it worked fine for me - for context I was getting this when I was doing db:migrate. fyi